# Swiftmailer on Symfony 4 - fwrite() warning

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, swiftmailer

I am testing my Symfony 4 app and I configured my .env file like this:

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://mail.something.com:465?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=something@something.com&password=ABCDEFGH&encryption=ssl
```

In command prompt I have used standard mail testing command:

```
php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send
```

but I've got an error:

> [OK] 1 emails were successfully sent.
>
> In StreamBuffer.php line 231:
>   Warning: fwrite(): SSL: Operacja ukoczona pomylnie.

which can be translated to "Operation completed successfully" (I'm using polish Windows 10).

Email was not sent. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you try adding a LoggerPlugin to the mailer instance and give us its output ? I got a similar behaviour when trying to send emails using TLS on a non-TLS mailer.